# Pass keyword arg to log handler in python logging configuration file

Tags: python, logging, configuration

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format I can specify arguments to the constructor of a logger, by using the `args` key. But this seems to work only for positional arguments. I have a handler which needs some keyword arguments. Is there a way to specify those in the config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that the answer is **no**.

Have a look at https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/config.py#l163 for more details.

When in doubt, the source code is always your friend!

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't agree the answer is just no.

You can put your keyword arguments in a row, like in this example with SysLogHandler, what has no positional arguments, only keyword ones:

> class logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address=('localhost',
>   SYSLOG_UDP_PORT), facility=LOG_USER, socktype=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

```
[handler_mainHandler]
class=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler
level=INFO
formatter=defaultFormatter
args=('/dev/log','myapp')
```

Python will take '/dev/log' as address keyword argument and 'myapp' as facility argument. They are handled the order they show up.

Such an example is in the documentation for both [python2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format) and [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format):

```
[handler_hand05]
class=handlers.SysLogHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=form05
args=(('localhost', handlers.SYSLOG_UDP_PORT), handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_USER)
```

There are some disadvantages though:

- it's not very readable
- it's limited: if you need to access to an external library, the use of `ext://` does not work well. In such a case, I would suggest to turn the old style configuration file into a yaml one, like described in my question/answer here: [How to refer to a standard library in a logging configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770053/how-to-refer-to-a-standard-library-in-a-logging-configuration-file)

'Upgrading' the old-style written config file into a yaml written one allows to use keyword arguments in a better and more explicit way. Note that the documentation, as well for [python2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) and [python3](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) talks explicitely about keyword arguments:

> The callable will be called with the remaining items in the
>   configuration sub-dictionary as keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Using YAML (not *.ini*), if you use the *()* special key instead of the *class* keyword, all the  properties at the same level will be passed as arguments to the constructor.

E.g. using an external formatter, this will ignore the *log_colors* parameter:

```
formatters:
  class:
    class: colorlog.ColoredFormatter
    log_colors: { DEBUG: 'cyan', INFO: 'green', WARNING: 'yellow', ERROR: 'red', CRITICAL: 'red,bg_white' }
    format: '%(log_color)s[%(asctime)s-%(shorter_levelname)s-%(compact_name)s]%(message)s'
    datefmt: '%H:%M:%S'
```

This instead will work:

```
formatters:
  color:
    (): colorlog.ColoredFormatter
    log_colors: { DEBUG: 'cyan', INFO: 'green', WARNING: 'yellow', ERROR: 'red', CRITICAL: 'red,bg_white' }
    format: '%(log_color)s[%(asctime)s-%(shorter_levelname)s-%(compact_name)s]%(message)s'
    datefmt: '%H:%M:%S'
```